# Angular $http, load json - does it create array on $scope

Tags: json, angularjs

Still new to Angularjs so still finding my feet.

I'm trying to load a json file from a URL using the $http service.

The `console.log('done')` output `done`, so I think it's working.

The `console.log($scope.tabs)` outputs `Array[0]`.

The `console.log(typeof tabs === 'array' ? 'yes' : 'no')` outputs `no`

Does `$scope.tabs = tabs;` create an array on the `$scope` object?

```
            var app = angular.module('pageApp',[]);


            app.controller('ContentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

              $scope.loadTabs = function() {

                    $http({
                    url: '/category',
                    method: 'GET'
                })
                .success(function(tabs) {
                    $scope.tabs = tabs;
                    console.log('done');
                    console.log($scope.tabs);
                    console.log(typeof tabs === 'array' ? 'yes' : 'no');
                })
                .error(function(response) {
                  console.log('error');
                });
                }

              $scope.loadTabs();

            }]);
```

Comment: can you do a console.log for your tabs before assigning the value to $scope.tabs? This will help you to understand the data coming from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typeof` operator returns 6 possible values, `array` is none of them. You can use `tabs instanceof Array ? 'yes' : 'no'` instead.